# Can't login from console after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading to 22.04 LTS, I can no longer login from the console to the user who did the upgrade. I can login to another user.
I also can login to that user from SSH. no error message appears on the console. It just sends me back to the initial screen where all users are listed.
No clue what the issue is.

Comment: Found the problem...GDM was started by crontab and took over from Lightdm.  Removed GDM and all is working fine